# How to check if an list of objects contains a key from a List of strings

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Hello I'm still new to Java. I have a List of objects called **formData** coming from the UI which looks like this:

```
[
 {
   fieldName: "phone",
   value: "1111111111"
 {
[
```

I have a List of strings called **requiredTypes** that represent my keys that I need to check which is:

```
["phone", "DOB"]
```

I want to be able to loop through **formData** to see if my formData has these types in **requiredTypes**. If the fieldNames in **formData** contains these types from **requiredTypes** then return true. If not, return false.

So for this case, it will return false because it's missing a **DOB**.

I tried using **Java 8** Streams to see if I could make the comparison but it's returning void

```
  val hasFormType = formData.stream().forEach(fieldData -> 
    requiredTypes.forEach(requiredType -> 
    requiredType.contains(fieldData.getFieldName())));
```

Am I misusing streams? Is there a better approach to this case? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the field names to a set and compare it to the collection of required fields

```
Set<String> existingFields = formData.stream()
    .map(FieldData::getFieldName).collect(Collectors.toSet());

val hasFormType = existingFields.containsAll(requiredTypes);
```